# Node.js creating multiple live feeds, how to serve

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am currently making a live feed.
There are multiple users, who can follow multiple users.
The goal is to create a live feed for every user, so User A sees what User B & C writes and User B sees what User A writes. It shouldn't be necessary to reload the page to see new messages -> so fetching new messages somehow using JavaScript and writing them to the body using AngularJS/jQuery.

My first idea is to create one huge socket, where every new message would be committed to and the client checks if there is a message for him. But this would be to easy too manipulate and too heavy, am I mistaking?

Another idea is to create a route like `api.page.tld/feed/:username` and everytime, when a new messages is made, the server looks which user follows the recipient and then pushes to every subroute the new message. So every subroute would give out a user feed with the last 10 messages. Would this cause heavy load?

Comment: Have you checked the socket.io lib?

Comment: To which part do you refer? I just took a few quick looks at it, so I would rather say no.